# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{2z}{z-kn}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Can we turn this sum into a simpler form ?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{2z}{z-kn}=\Gamma(2z+1)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(z-kn+1)\Gamma(z+kn+1)} \qquad;\qquad (z;n)\in \mathbb C \times \mathbb N$$

Can we just give a closed form to the sum when $z$ is integer ?

(This question is part of a search on a new formula of the zeta function that I manipulate to make it simpler.)

Comment: For n=1,2,4,5,6 Maple finds an expression of the form $-{\Gamma(2z+1)\over2\Gamma(z+1)^2}$ plus a finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^rc_ka_k^z$; in other cases more complicated hypergeometric expressions.

Comment: [Series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) can turn this into a sum of $n$ terms.

Comment: I see now that the Gamma term that is subtracted in the Maple's result, is just   ${1\over2}{2z\choose z}$; adding it to the sum as a term for $k=0$ should give a simpler result. Also, the complete sum for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ should be $4^z$, independently of $n$.

Comment: Also note that for $z\in\mathbb{N}$ it is already a finite sum, that one could consider first.

Comment: $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \binom{2z}{z-kn} =\binom{2z}{z} + 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{2z}{z-kn}$, so $4^z$ is not the sum for $k\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Binomial coefficients are zero whenever the lower index is not an integer. So, the sum is zero whenever $z$ is not an integer.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev, counter-example : $\binom{2}{1/2}=\frac{16}{3\pi}$

Comment: @L.L: I don't know how you define binomial coefficients, but by the conventional definition $\binom{n}{k}$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^n$. For $n=2$, we have $(1+x)^2 = 1+2x+x^2$, where the coefficient of $x^{1/2}$ is zero. E.g., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series

Comment: @Max Alekseyev, this is the general définition : $z$ et $s$ complexes numbers :$\displaystyle  \binom{z}{s} = \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma(z-s+1)}$

Comment: @L.L: Then you'd better avoid using binomial notation as this definition contradicts the conventional one.

Comment: There could be a known formula, because Maple does it in single cases; yet apparently it takes more and more time to do $n=7,8,\dots$. In any cases, some of us now would be curious  to see the result, if it is known. So I don't really see a sufficient reason to close the question.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev What you recalled is the definition for *integer* $k$ (and $n\in\mathbb{C})$. But I wouldn't (and nobody does) take it as a definition for non-integer $k$. Also note that defining $x!:=\Gamma(x+1)$ is standard for $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_{-}$, and that ${z\choose s}:={z!\over s!(z-s)!}$.

Comment: @PietroMajer: The problem is that one has to be careful about extending one particular definition to a larger domain as many properties typically assumed for binomial coefficients may break. E.g., the definition via gamma functions does not fit the generating functions, and does not allow to compute values at negative integers.

Comment: @L.L: For an integer $z$, we have $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \binom{2z}{z-kn} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left(2\cos \frac{\pi j}{n}\right)^{2z}.$$ I don't know though if this extends well to complex values of $z$.

Comment: This is very nice

Comment: $\big(2 \cos(\pi j/n) \big)^2$ for $j=0,\dots,n-1$ are the roots of some integer-valued monic polynomial, so,for any fixed $n$, the values you got for integer $z$ solve an $n$ terms linear recurrence with integer coefficients

Comment: @PietroMajer: $\cos(\pi j/n)$ for $j=1,\dots,n-1$ are the zeros of Chebyshev polynomial $U_{n-1}(x)$.

Comment: There is a direct relation between the sum in the question and the sum $ \sum_ {k = 1} ^ {\infty} \frac1 {k^{1 + 2z}} $ which gives $\zeta (1 + 2z)$. I want to continue studying this question here and I hope the re-opening soon.

Comment: So I guess one can prove the same linear recurrence with characteristic polynomial $U_{n-1}$ for $S(z):=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {z\choose z/2-kn}$, even along any non integer sequence of $z$. (I mean $S(z), S(z+1) , S(z+2),\dots,S(z+n).$

Comment: This is not very practical (and is thus left as a comment), but your sum can be recast as a [Fox $H$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function).